# Plotting multiple lists of complex numbers

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, complex

The user #Nasser showed an elegant way to plot complex numbers:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}] + I RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {30}];

p = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ data,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
    ImagePadding -> 40,
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]]];

Show[p, Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

How can I change this code so that an input of multiple lists is possible and they are plotted each in a different color?

Answer (score 4):

I propose using this function to process your complex numbers:

```
complexSplit = Function[z, {Re@z, Im@z}, Listable];
```

It works on multiple list shapes:

```
complexSplit[3.7 + 2.1 I]
complexSplit[{3.7 + 2.1 I, 5.7 + 4.4 I}]
complexSplit[{{3.7 + 2.1 I, 5.7 + 4.4 I}, {8.1 + 3.7 I}, 4.2 + 5.1 I}]
```

> ```
> {3.7, 2.1}
>
> {{3.7, 2.1}, {5.7, 4.4}}
>
> {{{3.7, 2.1}, {5.7, 4.4}}, {{8.1, 3.7}}, {4.2, 5.1}}
> ```

Next I use this to create three lists of complex numbers:

```
data = {1, I}.# & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2, 50}]
```

Or as Rojo reminded me, more simply:

```
data = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {3, 50}];
```

I can then plot all three lists in a single `ListPlot` expression:

```
ListPlot[complexSplit @ data,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, ImagePadding -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[#, PointSize[.02]] & /@ {Purple, Darker@Green, Orange}),
 Epilog -> Circle[{0, 0}, 1]
]
```

[image]

I can plot only the first list by using:

```
ListPlot[complexSplit @ {First @ data},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, ImagePadding -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[#, PointSize[.02]] & /@ {Purple, Darker@Green, Orange}),
 Epilog -> Circle[{0, 0}, 1]
]
```

[image]

Note that I added a `List` level (`{ }`); this is to keep each point from being plotted as a different color.  Note also that the points from the first list are not colored the same as they are in the first plot; if you wish to preserve coloring you can replace any list you do not wish to plot with `Indeterminate`.  Here I will plot the first and third lists using the same coloring as plotting all three:

```
ListPlot[complexSplit @ ReplacePart[data, 2 -> Indeterminate],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, ImagePadding -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[#, PointSize[.02]] & /@ {Purple, Darker@Green, Orange}),
 Epilog -> Circle[{0, 0}, 1]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Just because I know you wouldn't like to have missed a built-in, I have to check: you don't know about `RandomComplex` or you chose against it?

Comment: @Rojo Honestly I forgot about it, `Dot` is the first thing that came to mind and I hoped it would interest the OP.  Thanks for reminding me.  For some reason I never seem to use *random* complex numbers; I'll take this as a challenge to change that.

Comment: No problem. Even with `Dot`, you could also do `{1, I}.RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3, 50}]`

Comment: @Rojo It's just not my day. :^)

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.1 there is `ComplexListPlot`

Using Mr. Wizard's data

```
data = {1, I} . # & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2, 50}]; 

ComplexListPlot[data,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 AxesStyle -> White,
 Background -> Black,
 Epilog -> {White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}},
 FrameStyle -> White,
 ImagePadding -> 40,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}]
```

[image]

Another example

```
ComplexListPlot[
 {NestList[(0.9 + 0.1 I) # &, 1 + I, 30], 
  NestList[(0.9 + 0.2 I) # &, 1 + I, 30]},
 Joined -> {True, False},
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
 PlotLegends -> {0.1, 0.2}]
```

[image]